# Constraint syntax compaction

Tags: syntax, mathematical-optimization, expression-construction

Is there a more compact way to represent these constraints:

`NMaximize[{a+b+c,`**`a <= 5 && b <= 5 && c <= 5`**`}, {a,b,c}]`

like `for x in {a,b,c}, x <= 5` or something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I personally like to use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) for such things (bounds are e.g. easy to adjust), like:

```
NMaximize[{a + b + c, Thread[{a, b, c} <= {5, 6, 7}]}, {a, b, c}]
```

If it is all the same bound, we can directly write (as in Artes' comment below):

```
NMaximize[{a + b + c, Thread[{a, b, c} <= 5]}, {a, b, c}]
```

I think the syntax should be clear - see also Docu Center for a very similar example (on [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html))

Also see Artes' comment below for further ideas based on the (exemplary) function you provide.

Comment: `NMaximize[{a + b + c, Thread[{a, b, c} <= 5]}, {a, b, c}]` or simply `NMaximize[{a + b + c, Thread[# <= 5]}, #] &@{a, b, c}`, or `NMaximize[{Plus @@ #, Thread[# <= 5]}, #] &@{a, b, c}`.

Comment: Thanks @Artes, I added that to the list and made clear that my previous answer was gear towards different bounds

Comment: Thanks.
Thread[] seems similar to Haskell's generalized map "fmap" (Functor).

Answer (score 7):

If you do these things a lot you may consider building your own syntax to be able to write constraints in a more concise manner, e.g.:

```
constrAnd[list_, func_] := And @@ (func /@ list)
lt[list_,n_] := constrAnd[{a, b, c}, # <= n &]
lt[{a, b, c},5]
```

> a <= 5 && b <= 5 && c <= 5

So that you may now write

```
NMaximize[{a + b + c, lt[{a, b, c}, 5]}, {a, b, c}]
```

This function is logically equivalent to the example in the OP, "for x in ...".

Answer (score 6):

What about this (because `NMinimize` also accepts a list of boundary conditions):

```
NMaximize[{a + b + c, # <= 5 & /@ {a, b, c}}, {a, b, c}]
```

or (if you are after the very same expression)

```
NMaximize[{a + b + c, And @@ (# <= 5 & /@ {a, b, c})}, {a, b, c}]
```

Both are obviously not more compact as such, but very easily adapted to larger number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If all elements of your list share the same upper bound, you can write 
    Max[{a,b,c}]<5